# iPad Apps with nice transitions/animations

Tags: ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I hope I'm right here, if not please point me to another location to ask my question ;-)

I need to assemble a small showcase (research for a project at work) of Apps for the iPad that have nice view-to-view transitions / animations of objects. I already looked around on Google, and some Blogs and found some stuff, but I'm still missing the "Killer App" that has awesome transitions.

Anyone in the know of Apps that have what I'm looking for?

This is what I already have:

- A concept that features a nice navigation (http://momo.brauchtman.net/2011/09/16/ipad-app-concept-based-on-a-fluid-layout/)
- Jamie Oliver Recipes
- Flipboard
- Pulse News
- Volkswagen Das. (DE)

#### Rules

- **One** app per answer.
- Use this format for the first and second lines of your answer:
  **`## [app name](link to website)`**
  **`[App Store](link to appstore) (price in usd)`**
- Include a short **description**.
- **Check for duplicates** before adding new answers.

Any addition to this list is appreciated. If you just have a video that shows a concept, I'm also fine with that, must not be a released App.

Answer (score 1):

Try Jamie Olivers remarkably well designed **[20 Minute Meals](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/20-minute-meals-jamie-oliver/id318926433?mt=8)** app:

Also, in the first iPad year, **[Flipboard](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flipboard/id358801284?mt=8)** was awarded best app, and it has some very nice transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

- **[Apple Trailers](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-movie-trailers/id471966214)** 
  (recommended)
- **[Bloomberg TV](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bloomberg-tv/id460459302)**
- **[Wired Magazine](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wired-magazine/id373903654)**: 
  Free interactive demo articles can be downloaded within the app if you are not a subscriber.
- **[Weather HD](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/weather-hd/id364193735)**
- **[Design Scene](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/designscene/id412753716)**
- **[The Fantastic Flying Books of Mr. Morris Lessmore](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-fantastic-flying-books/id438052647)**:
  More interaction than navigation but worth mentioning because of the transitions.
- **[Appstream](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appstream-for-ipad/id375288393)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, will have a look at the Apps. Seems like Apple Trailers is not available in the German App Store :/

Comment: Just create a US account sans credit card. You can then download all the free apps in the US store that are not available where you are. Once created it's easy to switch between the two accounts as needed. Here's a guide: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for some really smooth animations in games, I'd highly recommend checking out [Gesundheit!](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/gesundheit!/id449344432?mt=8) by Konami Digital. Some really good animations for characters in the game. Hope this helped! :)